# Alternatives to using get_pages in WordPress to get children page data

Tags: wordpress

I am using get_pages to fetch some data from the children pages of a parent in WordPress (like a custom loop) - but it doesnt work when trying to fetch some data as set by the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for some strange reason... Is there an alternative / better way to acheive what I want? Code below works apart from fetching the ACF field called 'job_title'.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
  'parent' => $post->ID,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'sort_order' => 'DESC',
  'sort_column" => "post_name',
  'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC'
); 
$pages = get_pages($args);  ?>
<div class="childrenFetchedLoopWrapper">
<?php foreach( $pages as $page ) { ?>
<div class="feedItemWrapper wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_fadeInUp fadeInUp" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($page->ID, 'full'); ?>')">
<a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($page->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>">
<img src="/wp-content/themes/salient-child/images/aspectTrans.png" alt="*" title="*" />
<h3><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h3>
<p><?php the_field('job_title'); ?></p>

</a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Try replacing <?php the_field('job_title'); ?> with  <?php the_field('job_title', $page->ID); ?>.  Or try out the code using WP_Query.

Comment: <?php the_field('job_title'); ?> only works in a post template or in a post loop otherwise you have to pass the post_id in both function the_field() and get_field().

Comment: if you have solved your issue mark answer as accepted and Upvote it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `<?php the_field('job_title'); ?>` with `<?php the_field('job_title', $page->ID); ?>`.

OR

You can use WP_Query for alternative solution.
or you can also get acf value using get_post_meta();

Try Out this code. I hope it helps.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );


$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); 
        $id = get_the_ID(); ?>
        <p><?php the_field('job_title', $id); ?></p>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```